# Windows 10 version 1809 won't displayActiveX control on Word 365

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office365

I have a Word template with a single custom ActiveX control. The view from Word 365 on Windows 10 version 1803 and earlier display correctly.

The same template from Word 365 on Windows 10 version 1809 displays nothing on the UserForm.

Adding the custom control on a new Template/Document in Word 365 /Windows 10 version 1809 displays correctly. Once the new Template/Document is saved, the ActiveX Control fails to display as do all subsequent attempts to add the control to this saved document/template.

Does anyone out there know how I could correct this?

Comment: I'd say, uninstall the update and wait for the next one, which may take care of the problem. And maybe complain to Microsoft in order to be sure they're aware ofthe problem. But first check whether the problem is only with the custom ActiveX control. If it is, it's possible the control doesn't meet some kind of security standard.

Comment: Thanks Cindy for your response. It appears that Microsoft ActiveX controls are OK. Maybe, my custom ActiveX that is not meeting the security standard. Any idea what security changes applied ActiveX controls between Windows 10 version 1803 and 1809?